# Strip length does not update with sequence length

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When I add a Sequence as a Strip in the Sequencer, and then increase the length of my sequence, the strip does not take into account the new length and always stops. Is there a way to update the strip so it contains the whole length of the sequence?

Here you can see that my strip is ending at the playhead

[image]

After adding the sequence again, it works as expected.

Comment: I've made a bug report here: https://developer.blender.org/T76222
As an alternative, the Hold offset values can be changed in the Time sidebar panel(the values are really odd, but it is possible to make it longer)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't code a solution for you, but do you have additional questions?

Comment: Thanks @tintwotin! I wasn't able to get it to work with a hold offset, but I'll try. A fix for that would obviously be best :)